# How does one write a Hibernate "UserType" where the type has a collection in it?

Tags: hibernate

I have a Validity object which contains two dates, start and end.  I have a UserType that I've written for this so that I can simplify the hibernate mappings for the several entities that have one.  That works fine.

Now I want to add a set of weekdays to Validity.  The only solution I can figure out is to change each entity to treat Validity as a component, with the weekdays mapped as a .

Is there some way to use do this with a *UserType?

```
class Validity {
  Date start;
  Date end;
  Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek;
}

enum DayOfWeek {SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of the set come from an `enum,` can you map (encode) each possible value of `daysOfWeek` set to a database value and write a UserType instance to manage the translation? For eg something like where `{ SUNDAY, TUESDAY, THURSDAY }` maps to `1010100`.

Edit: This would make querying the database by applications other than yours a pain.

Comment: This is what we've decided to do in this case, but we have other cases where it's not an enum but user-entered data and thus not possible.  So I'd still like to find a general solution to the problem.

Comment: @David Corbin, I don't think `UserType`s are created with the usecase you have in mind. They are supposed to map to the one or more columns of the same table as the parent entity. The general solution you strive for is better achieved by using a 1:N mapping, IMHO.